# How do I find the sum of this series?

Tags: analysis, summation

This is part of a homework assignment so I'm only looking for a hint on how to solve this.

The question is to find the sum of the series $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n-1)3^{n-1}}$

I have no idea how to even begin. Thanks.